# How to sort an array list of dicts by the dicts value place?

Tags: python

**Skip this part** it's not needed but its a precursor to the movie

From my list, I get every possible combination by doing the following

```
list = {
        "list1": [
            {"name", "height", 10000000000},
            {"name1", "height2", 90000000000}
        ],

        "list2": [
            {"name", "height", 30000000000},
            {"name1", "height2", 40000000000}
        ],
        "list3": [
            {"name", "height", 50000000000},
            {"name1", "height2", 60000000000}
        ]
    }

keys = list .keys()
values = (list [key] for key in keys)
combinations = [dict(zip(keys, combination)) for combination in itertools.product(*values)]
```

This gives me

```
print(combinations)
[{'list1': {10000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {30000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {50000000000, 'height', 'name'}}, {'list1': {10000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {30000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {60000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}}, {'list1': {10000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {40000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list3': {50000000000, 'height', 'name'}}, {'list1': {10000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {40000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list3': {60000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}}, {'list1': {90000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list2': {30000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {50000000000, 'height', 'name'}}, {'list1': {90000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list2': {30000000000, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {60000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}}, {'list1': {90000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list2': {40000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list3': {50000000000, 'height', 'name'}}, {'list1': {90000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list2': {40000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}, 'list3': {60000000000, 'name1', 'height2'}}]
```

**READ FROM HERE**

What I now need is to take the `combinations` array and order them based on the sum of each combinations dictionarys values at the value with the integer

Assuming we have the first 3 combos for brevity:
(removed the extra zeros)

```
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {3, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {5, 'height', 'name'}}, 
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {3, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {6, 'name', 'height'}}, 
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {4, , 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {5, 'height', 'name'}}
```

I want to order them like this:
The following takes the sum of each of the field that has integers
The order will be:

10

10

9

**resulting in:** **(goal output)**

```
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {3, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {6, 'height', 'name'}}, 
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {4, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {5, 'height', 'name'}}
{'list1': {1, 'height', 'name'}, 'list2': {3, 'height', 'name'}, 'list3': {5, 'height', 'name'}},
```

How can I accomplish this?

As a bonus issue, if I were to add another value to dict like:

```
...
"list1": [
    {"name", "height", 10000000000, true},
    {"name1", "height2", 90000000000, true}
], ...
```

How could i also order it by the sum of the value-->[3] and also the boolean.  In case the numbers are equal like in the example above

Comment: Sry, but I dont unterstand what you mean by `value-->[2]` as there is no variable `value` in your code and`-->[2]` is not python syntax. Since you say that `value-->[2]` refers to 'the integer', do you mean the index-2 element of `{'name', 'hight', 10000}`? That does not make any sense, because `{...}` is a set and doesnt support indexing/slicing.

Comment: If you chose smaller integer numbers for your example, one could at least understand the arithmetics of what you want to achieve without getting lost in counting zeros.

Comment: Your initial data structure is probably not what you think it is. The way you have written it, it is a dict whose values are two-element lists of three-element sets each. Maybe a bit of context as to what you are trying to actually achieve is in order.

Comment: I'm not too good at remembering termonolgy my bad but i want to take the combinations results and order it by the sum of the integer value

Comment: @H.Doebler I updated with more context

Comment: @ChristianKuhl meant to tag you as well --- i added more information on what i'm trying to do. If it still isn't explain well lmk.

Comment: Erh... `list` is a really bad name for a dict.

Comment: @KellyBundy lol true that

Comment: @BobLinux The issue with `list` as a variable name for a dictionary is not just that it is confusing, it is also shadowing the Python builtin type `list`, i.e. after the first assignment you wouldn't be able to convert stuff into a proper Python list.

Comment: @ChristianKuhl I'm not actully using tha tin prodduction but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that sums all `int`s in all values of a dict an use that as sort key?

```py
from itertools import chain

def sum_keys_ints(d):
    return sum(i for i in chain(*d.values()) if isinstance(i, int))

combinations.sort(key=sum_keys_ints, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Of course one could inline that function as lambda into the call of `sort` for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it took me this long but i woke up in the middle of the night realizing I was an idiot and figured it out in 20 seconds and went back to sleep

I ended up naming the values as well:

```
sorted(combinations, key=lambda x: sum(i['value_name'] for i in x.values()), reverse=True)
```